# How to send message from backend(java) to frontend(react)

Tags: java, reactjs, axios

Hi Im still learning how to use react and java. I am creating a project where the front end is in react and the backend is in java.

I was wondering if someone would be able to point me in the right direction or give me an example of java sending a message to the front end in react. What Im essentially trying to do is give the user a message after the backend receives a file they submit. I already have the part where the backend is processing the file.

Ive tried looking at a lot of sites but theres not a lot of documentation out there for react and java as the backend.

thank you

Comment: What you are asking is web socket. Take a search for it.

Comment: Spring MVC could be an option-https://medium.com/@pietroghezzi/spring-and-react-js-the-easy-way-5abe8a529058

Comment: Submit file asynchronously, when it is processed, the UI will get response back. You can handle call/response via promise. it is not customary for the server to call web client; a single server may have thousands or millions of clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is Websocket, he provide a full-duplex communication channels over a single TCP connection. So, when you start a comunication between client and server, a session is created, making possible to send and receive message for both side.

Some possibilities are, use javax:

1. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/package-summary.html
2. https://www.baeldung.com/java-websockets

Use spring-websocket(if are you already using spring, will be easy to use):

1. https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/
2. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html

Here is another example with javax https://www.pegaxchange.com/2018/01/28/websocket-server-java/

So, there are a lot of examples.

Answer (score 2):

Websocket would open a channel between the client and the server, so you can send a server message at any time.
But, if you are already using a POST from the client to upload the file, you could just send a response to the POST.